# Colors don't show using persp3d() function in R

Tags: r, function, graph, colors, 3d

I'm having some issues when using persp3d() function in R. Here is my code:

```
    library(rgl)
    vero=function(mu,sigma,datos)
    {
        n=length(datos)
        media=mean(datos)
        S2=sd(datos)^2
        lvero=(-n/2)*log(2*pi*sigma)-(n/(2*sigma))*S2-(n/(2*sigma))*(media-mu)^2
        return(exp(lvero))
    }

    nbebes=rnorm(20, mean=75, sd=2.5)
    mu.seq <- seq(60,100,length=2000)
    sigma.seq <- seq(1,20,length=2000)


    f <- Vectorize(vero,vectorize.args=c("mu","sigma"))
    z <- outer(mu.seq,sigma.seq,f,datos=nbebes)
    zlim <- range(z[!is.na(z)])
    palette <- rev(rainbow(20))
    colors <- palette[19*(z-zlim[1])/diff(zlim) + 1] 

    persp3d(mu.seq,sigma.seq,z,col=colors)
```

And the output of the code is this graph:

[image]
What am I doing wrong? Sometimes I get another result which is a rainbow colored function like this one:

[image]
But as you can see it is not completely colored and I don't know what to change or rewrite to get the proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say eaxactly why this is an issue, but it seems to have to do with the limits of your z-axis. When I rescale `z` to `z2 <- z / max(z)` then it ranges between 0 and 1 and plots well. This might be an issue with `rgl`. Here's an example:

```
nbebes=rnorm(20, mean=75, sd=2.5)
mu.seq <- seq(60,100,length=500)
sigma.seq <- seq(1,20,length=500)

f <- Vectorize(vero,vectorize.args=c("mu","sigma"))
z <- outer(mu.seq,sigma.seq,f,datos=nbebes)
z2 <- z/max(z)
colors <- rev(rainbow(20))
breaks <- seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out=(length(colors)+1))
CUT <- cut(z2, breaks=breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)
colorlevels <- colors[match(CUT, levels(CUT))] # assign colors to heights for each point

persp3d(mu.seq,sigma.seq,z2,color=colorlevels)
```

[image]